# C# Localization Language files (resx)?

Tags: c#, localization

Hi im new to C# and localization, i got it to work, but i was wondering if there were any pre-made language (resx) files available for download or should i create them myself from scratch?

thanks

Bart

Comment: Your localization needs will be specific for you application - of course no one created resource files that will work for your application.

Comment: localization is made for translating the "strings" of *your* application to different language. How do you expect to find it on internet?

Comment: okay thanks, i thought maybe there would be some translation libraries or something, guess i'll build the resx files myself.

Comment: I have found an online tool that may be helpful to anyone looking for an automated tool to translate a resx to another language. https://localise.biz/free/converter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're two ways of understanding your question.

If it's:

**a.** *You want a generic, common RESX contaning typical words in an application... I don't think so.*

**b.** *You want to create a RESX and you need to manually create the XML file and its strongly-typed version as a class to easly access it in your application: no.*

For "**a**" I don't have anything to add to the explanation, but regarding "**b**", just go to Visual Studio and right-click on your project or on a project folder, choose "Add new item" and look for the resources file item, click on "Add", and that's all.

Comment: okay thanks, i thought maybe there would be some translation libraries or something, guess i'll build the resx files myself. (i meant a)

Comment: @BartHofma Yeah, what else? ;)

Comment: well i guess my question is anwsered so nothing else :P